# why is my python code(seaborn, lmplot) is not working?

Tags: python, seaborn

i learned python seaborn lib.

i found a code like this in web.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
scatter = sns.lmplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips, hue='sex', fit_reg=False, markers=['o','x']
                     , scatter_kws={"s" : tips['size']})
plt.show()
```

but, Error happens like this

```
ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y
```

why... is not working? i don't know what to do

Comment: i just want to resize by using tips['size]. tips['size'] is number data differently. If i want to change size all data differently, how could i do...?

Comment: Mixing seaborn and matplotlib can be tricky when hue is involved. You might try to draw the lmplot without scatter and then call sns.scatterplot in a separate step.

Comment: `fit_reg=False` means you're just doing a scatterplot. `p = sns.scatterplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips, size='size', hue='sex')`